# Fast tensor initialisation in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to initialize a 3d tensor (multi-dimensional array) with the values of the "diagonal Gaussian"

```
exp(-32*(u^2 + 16*(v^2 + w^2)))
```

where `u = 1/sqrt(3)*(x+y+z)`  and `v,w` are any two coordinates orthogonal to `u`, discretised on a uniform mesh on `[-1,1]^3`. The following code achieves this:

```
function gaussian3d(n)
    q = qr(ones(3,1), thin=false)[1]
    x = linspace(-1.,1., n)
    p = Array(Float64,(n,n,n))
    square(x) = x*x
    Base.@nloops 3 i p begin
        @inbounds p[i_1,i_2,i_3] = 
            exp(
                -32*(
                    square(q[1,1]*x[i_1] + q[2,1]*x[i_2] + q[3,1]*x[i_3])
                    + 16*(
                        square(q[1,2]*x[i_1] + q[2,2]*x[i_2] + q[3,2]*x[i_3]) + 
                        square(q[1,3]*x[i_1] + q[2,3]*x[i_2] + q[3,3]*x[i_3])
                    )
                )
            )
    end
    return p
end
```

It seems to be quite slow, however. For example, if I replace the defining function with `exp(x*y*z)`, the code runs 50x faster. Also, the `@time` macro reports ~20% GC time for the above code which I do not understand where they come from. (These numeric values were obtained with `n = 128`.) My questions therefore are

- How can I speed up this piece of code?
- Where is the memory allocation hidden which causes the GC overhead?

Comment: Try defining your ``square`` function at the top-level or module-level scope. Inner functions are not well optimized.

Comment: Defining `square` at the top level seems to increase the performance somewhat, but the gain is only little above the uncertainty in timing.

Comment: Just curious, is there a use for this tensor?  It has exceptionally small values *and* spans hundreds of orders of magnitude.

Comment: We use it as a test case for our compression algorithm. One of the points there is exactly that you can drop the small values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing nothing of 3D tensors with values of the "diagonal Gaussian", using the`square` comment from the original post, "typing" `q` ([`@code_warntype` helps here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#man-code-warntype): Big performance jump!), and further specializing the `@nloops`, this works much faster on the platforms I tried it on.

```
julia> square(x::Float64) = x * x
square (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function my_gaussian3d(n)
           q::Array{Float64,2} = qr(ones(3,1), thin=false)[1]
           x = linspace(-1.,1., n)
           p = Array(Float64,(n,n,n))
           Base.@nloops 3 i p d->x_d=x[i_d] begin
               @inbounds p[i_1,i_2,i_3] =
                   exp(
                       -32*(
                           square(q[1,1]*x_1 + q[2,1]*x_2 + q[3,1]*x_3)
                           + 16*(
                               square(q[1,2]*x_1 + q[2,2]*x_2 + q[3,2]*x_3) +
                               square(q[1,3]*x_1 + q[2,3]*x_2 + q[3,3]*x_3)
                           )
                       )
                   )
           end
           return p
       end
my_gaussian3d (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @time gaussian3d(128);
elapsed time: 3.952389337 seconds (1264 MB allocated, 4.50% gc time in 57 pauses with 0 full sweep)

julia> @time gaussian3d(128);
elapsed time: 3.527316699 seconds (1264 MB allocated, 4.42% gc time in 58 pauses with 0 full sweep)

julia> @time my_gaussian3d(128);
elapsed time: 0.285837566 seconds (16 MB allocated)

julia> @time my_gaussian3d(128);
elapsed time: 0.28476448 seconds (16 MB allocated, 1.22% gc time in 0 pauses with 0 full sweep)

julia> my_gaussian3d(128) == gaussian3d(128)
true
```

Comment: I do wonder if scaling `q` and performing a convolution (FFT-based?) might also generate the tensor.  There is also lots of symmetry here that duplicates calculations.  At least the redundancies could be reduced/eliminated.

Comment: Typing `q` is the key to performance. At first glance, I thought this was redundant since at the point of declaration the compiler could easily deduce the type of `q`, but skimming through the Julia manual once more I realised that this alone is not sufficient: we further need to promise to the compiler that we will never try to assign anything else to `q`! Being a Julia beginner myself, I think this is a point many fellow beginners will stumble upon, so maybe you want to highlight this in your answer more clearly. Thanks for your help, anyway!

Comment: No, you don't normally need to promise you won't change `q`'s type within a function: the compiler can figure that out for itself. It's likely to be type instability in the `qr` function. It would be worth opening an issue.

Comment: @tholy Thanks for making [a pull request to fix this issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/11240).